# setInterval with an object method only running once

Tags: javascript, setinterval

The following structure

```
function SomeObject() {}

SomeObject.prototype.repeatWhat = function() {
    setInterval(this.what, 1);
}

SomeObject.prototype.what = function() {
    console.log("what?");
}
```

Produces only a single `"what?"` in the console, why isn't it just running perpetually?

I call it like so

```
var someInstance = new SomeObject();
someInstance.what();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't calling `repeatWhat` in your code

```
var someInstance = new SomeObject();
someInstance.what();
someInstance.repeatWhat(); //I've added this
```

Comment: Well that was hard :D, sorry for taking up your time for this triviality... Thanks anyhow!

Comment: No problem, sometimes one just needs a fresh pair of eye to see that one missed the obvious :) Also, please accept the answer if it resolved your problem.

Comment: Oh absolutely, it just says that "9 minutes" till I'm able to accept :) so in due time my friend